# .eof() doesn't work outside the main function (C++)

Tags: c++, eof

I know that this may seem like a very basic question but why does .eof() work if it is in the main but not if it is in any other function?

Error:

```
error: request for member 'eof' in '((Lexer*)this)->Lexer::code', which is of non-class type 'std::ifstream* {aka std::basic_ifstream<char>*}'
```

Comment: Please provide more context.

Comment: @Kar you should usually post the relevant code since people can hardly ever answer solely with a single line error message. This time being an exception due to the exceptional clarity of the 2nd half of the error message (specifically: "which is of non-class type `std::ifstream*`").

Comment: You should not be using `eof()`.  Search StackOverflow for "c++ eof bad"

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have a pointer to the stream. Use `->` not `.` to access its members.

As the error messages says, there is a "request for member" (i.e. use of `.` to access a member) of a "non-class type '`std::ifstream*`'", (i.e. a pointer to `ifstream`).

Comment: How can we convince the newcomers that we are not mind-readers if you do just that?

Comment: @Dialecticus: It's not mind-reading, it's error-message reading. Just as rare a skill, though. ;-)

Comment: @DevSolar sadly most error messages aren't clear enough to answer. For this question it just happens that the error message is as clear as can be. Anyways +1 for beating me to answer.

Comment: @Dialecticus: OK, I've explained how to deduce this from the error message.